# Jquery get each div's sub child divs and grab info into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a some html that looks like this

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="sub_main_1" class="sub_main">
      <input type="text" class="sub_name_first" /><br />
      <input type="text" class="sub_name_second" /><br />
  </div>
  <div id="sub_main_2" class="sub_main">
      <input type="text" class="sub_name_first" /><br />
      <input type="text" class="sub_name_second" /><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to pull out each sub_main divs information into an array in javascript. So far I have this as my jquery code

```
$('#main').find('.sub_main').each( 
          function() { 
               alert('hi'); 
          });
```

The alert is just a test that it should show "hi" twice. But this is not working. I am also not clear on how I can store the two inputs in a javascript array. Any help would be great! Thanks,

Comment: not working - please be specific. what makes you think its not working. are you not seeing any alerts?

Comment: You want to store the `input` elements, or their values?

Comment: Not working how? No alerts at all?

Comment: There are no alerts therefore its not traversing or that is my theory. And I want to store the input values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var array = $('#main input').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

---

**EDIT:**

Note that this will return the values of all `input` elements under `#main`. You can make the `$('#main input')` selector as specific as you need if not all `input` elements are desired.

Answer (score 3):

```
var info = $("#main .sub_main input:text").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get(); // get() converts resulting collection into array
```

http://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 0):

Are you waiting for the DOM to load?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#main').find('.sub_main').each( 
          function() { 
               alert('hi'); 
     });
 });
```

Comment: I am actually running this in a javascript function, the DOM has alreayd been loaded and the javascript function is called from the page after it has been loaded to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pull out the child divs of your 'main' div, use

```
$('.main>div')
```

This will select all div children of anything with the class of 'main'.

Answer (score 0):

why not just do something simple like this:

```
var firsts = [];
var seconds = [];
("#main .sub_main input").each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   if($this.is(".sub_name_first"){
     firsts.push($this.val());
   } else {
     seconds.push($this.val());
   }
});
```

sure, its not the best way, but i just wrote that in 1 minute and it works