# Get all divs in a particular div using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this document structure

```
<div id="log">
<div>ABC</div>
<br/>
<div>DEF</div>
<br/>
...
</div>
```

Where `...` represents any number of div, br pairs.

Now I need to write a JQuery function called exists that takes an id (in this case "log") and a string (for example "DEF") and checks if in the "log" div there is any div whose text matches "DEF".  My JQuery is weak, can someone help me with this?

Comment: See this post, i believe this is a duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722582/jquery-get-each-divs-sub-child-divs-and-grab-info-into-an-array

Comment: Thanks all.  That was awesome.  Here's another question.  How do I get a list/array of the content of all the divs in "log"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ( $('#log div:contains("DEF")').length ) {
   // exists
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast, you are good.  Just tried this.  It works.  I don't understand why though.  Could you explain it?  I totally don't understand the use of .length.

Comment: @SachinKainth `length` returns the number of elements in the jQuery object, here if there is a div that contains the word `DEF` length value is more than `0` which is a truthy value in JavaScript, hence that element(s) exists.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#log").children("div").each(function(){
   if( $(this).text() == "DEF")
     //do something  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a selector string from the id, using the [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
function exists(id, content) {
  return $('#' + id + ' div:contains("' + content + '")').length > 0;
}
```

That however doesn't make an exact match. You would get a false positive if you want a div that contains exactly EAR, and there is a div containing BEARS. To make an exact match you can filter the elements using the [`filter` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
function exists(id, content) {
  return $('#' + id).filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == content;
  }).length > 0;
}
```

#### Edit:

To get the contents of all the divs, use the `map` method:

```
var arr = $('#' + id + ' div').map(function(){
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#log').find('div:contains("DEF")');
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$searchThis = $('.log').html();
if($searchThis.indexOf('search string') != -1){
    actions upon success (you found the string)
}
```